# fire event after element cycled with cycle.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

im using `cycle.js` for some basic transitions between some pictures:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var first;
    var $slider = $(".trauringe");
    $slider.cycle({
    timeout: 8000,
    next:   '#next', 
    prev:   '#prev' });
 });
```

what i would like to do is, to fire an event when the element "cycled" to the next one. Means when the next picture is faded in.

Any help much appreciated!

greets

Comment: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

Comment: you can use bfore option in cycle function call, like this ` before:  onBefore, `. then create a callback function for it ,`function onBefore() { 
    $('#output').html("Scrolling image:<br>" + this.src); 
}`

Comment: Hi supersize,  Both are same kind of answer. I answered much before the other person. I am not sure, why you accepted other person. Thanks,

Comment: well that is a good question, i guess because he was providing a fiddle where i could comprehend it much more! Is it common to give the accept to the person who answered earlier? if, then you'll get the accept!

Comment: its purely ur wish. I Just want to understand. thanks, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#s5').cycle({ 
fx:     'scrollLeft', 
timeout: 5000, 
before:  onBefore, 
after:   onAfter 
});


 function onBefore() { 
 $('#output').html("Scrolling image:<br>" + this.src); 
 } 
  function onAfter() { 
   $('#output').html("Scroll complete for:<br>" + this.src) 
      .append('<h3>' + this.alt + '</h3>'); 
  }
```

Here is a working example from [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/JEqE9/)

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use before / after.

For example,

```
$('#slide_cont').cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollLeft', 
    before:  onBefore, 
    after:   onAfter 
 });
function onBefore() { 
    $('#output').html("Scrolling image:<br>" + this.src); 
} 
function onAfter() { 
    $('#output').html("Scroll complete for:<br>" + this.src).append(this.alt); 
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! i should have more looks to the reference.